# How to pull information from Facebook profiles in batches using Power Query? (Or other methods)

Tags: jquery, excel, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping

I am the owner of a rather large (but very private) facebook group.  I wanted to see if I could go about, in large batches, grabbing all the personal information that is publicly available in the 'about me' section of my member's facebooks.  I have all of the URLs / profile names already ready to go, but I was having trouble automating the extraction of the group's information.  I have found that there's a useful plugin for Excel called Power Query that lets me do this, but so far I've only been able to do it manually. Here are the outputs from a dummy profile I made:

[Example of manual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KseWp.jpg)

This is what I'm trying to achieve, except automated for all accounts.

**Best case scenario**
Have a formula that can be used to point to the profile on FB which outputs the data separated by column separators.  As in, each variable has its own cell formula which would likely need little sanitization.

**Acceptable tier**
Have an automated way of going and pulling all the available data, leaving me to figure out how to sanitize the data later.

My preferred output would look like this:

> URL profileName Name Age City State Work Education

I realize this is a big ask but if there's formula available for Power Querying Facebook data points then I realize this might be possible albeit hard.

**NOTE: My group is a private, closed group for various reasons so I can't use the Facebook API**

This is the only avenue I can think of so if you have other methods I would like to hear that as well.

Comment: That is not allowed. The only allowed way is to use the API

Comment: Oh okay.  Thanks.

Comment: Just because people are members of your secret group, does not mean you have any right to access that kind of information.

Comment: I obviously didn't know it was against the rules as it was easy to scrape not even a year ago.  Save your moralizing for church.